# Company-mode always returns No completion found

Tags: python, company-mode

I start Emacs, open a python file, try autocompletion (my keybinding is `C-c i` to call `company-complete-mode`) and works well.

After run `pyvenv-workon RET myvenv` to activate my virtual enviroment, `company-complete-common` always returns `No completion found.`

company version: 0.94
emacs: 25.3.1 on Arch Linux x86_64

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`Company-mode` cannot complete your python code on his own. You need to install and configure [emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) (for example) to give company-mode candidates for completion.

Comment: How does it then work in a clean emacs install, there is for sure no jedi pre-installed ... ?